# How to check field axioms given addition and multiplication tables

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, field-theory, finite-fields

[image]

I need help with this question, i want to know the exact method of doing it with explanation. i am not able to get around with the logic of it.

Comment: The questions asks which of the axioms does not hold, if any. Have you managed to check some of the axioms already?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I've just edited the title to make it more descriptive and added some relevant tags. Please see [Help pages](http://math.stackexchange.com/help) for some hints on using this site. In particular, it's not a good practice to post questions like this including pictures - it's not possible to search the text on them. A minimal edit would be at least to retype the text and include only the picture of two tables.

Comment: oh okay, thanks for the information.

Comment: Look at the $x$ row or column in the multiplication table. Yer dead right there.  Not a field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the multiplication table, take a look at what happens when you multiply $x$ with itself.  Why is that a problem?

As for the method of doing it -- I just remembered what a field is defined to be: a commutative ring with a multiplicative identity, no zero divisors, and every element has a multiplicative inverse.  There are actually multiple reasons why this is *not* a field.  Take a look at the $x$ row in the multiplication table.  Do you see any $1$s belonging to that row?  No.  Why is that a problem?